# Is there a CDN for unstable versions of Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, cdn

I generally use CDNs for javascript libraries, but now I want to try something from the newest "release candidate" version of Angular.js  ( 1.2 at this time )

Is there a CDN that serves "unstable" new releases of Angular.js?
Or do I have to download it and serve it myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you go on [Angularjs](http://angularjs.org/) main site and you click on the Download button then you click on `unstable` and finally you have the CDN of the lastest unstable version of angular wich is for now :

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js

Answer (score 2):

Yes. AngularJS does have a snapshot of the latest build, this is the link http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.js.

You can go to this [link](http://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/) to see all available modules.

Comment: The URL provided by you is not a CDN. The other answer is correct.